Свой прогресс при выполнении команды ffmpeg
import subprocess as sub
from tqdm import tqdm
process = sub.Popen("ffmpeg -i /240.mp4 -c:v libaom-av1 -pix_fmt yuv420p /output.mkv", shell=True, stdout=sub.PIPE, stderr=sub.PIPE, text=True)
    with tqdm(total=100, desc="Processing", unit="%", ncols=100) as pbar:
        output = process.stdout.readline()
        error = process.stderr.readline()
        print(output)

Пытаюсь реализовать свой индикатор прогресса, параллельно записывать строчки что по дефолтному шаблону отображаются в консоле...
Что та не выходит, при выполнении, в консоли отображается
Processing:   0%|                                                            | 0                        /100 [00:00<?, ?%/s]

Будто бы завис...

Так это вообще никогда не работало. Для реализации таких штучек придётся запускать процессы отдельно, устраивать им обмен данными и прочая муть. Я видел в книжках описание подобного, сложно.

Да не, нормально. Просто кто-то забыл обновить прогресс

И цикла нет ещё

eri: Подправленный код? Мне тоже интересно.

Чтобы прогрессбар обновлялся, нужно либо чтобы tqdm использовался как итерируемый объект в цикле for, либо вручную дергать у него метод update по мере выполнения какой-то задачи. Вы ни то, ни другое не делаете. tqdm ничего не знает про subprocess, и магически к нему никак не привязывается.
